# Combining multiple sheets with the use of pastespecial xlpastevalues and xlpasteformats

Tags: vba, excel

I've been trying to combine multiple sheets in to one. I have already done it but when I tried to add a line of code

```
PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues).PasteSpecial(xlPasteFormats)
```

it leaves my combined sheet blank. Here is the code

```
On Error Resume Next
Sheets(1).Select
Worksheets.Add
Sheets(1).Name = "Consolidated"

Sheets(2).Activate
Range("A1").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1")

For Each s In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets
    If s.Name <> "Consolidated" And s.Name <> "Report" And s.Name <> 
       "Table" And s.Name <> "Values" And s.Name <> "Button" And s.Name <> 
       "PivotTable" And s.Name <> "Task" And s.Name <> "Mapping" 
        Then
        Application.GoTo Sheets(s.Name).[a1]
        Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
        Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
        Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Consolidated"). _
        Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(3) _
        .PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues).PasteSpecial(xlPasteFormats)  '<<-- The problem. It does not give me error but it only give me a blank cell everytime I add that line of code.

    End If
Next
```

Comment: *.PasteSpecial(xlPasteValues).PasteSpecial(xlPasteFormats)* `PasteSpecial` returns `Boolean` value. You true to use `PasteSpecial` on this type, but it doesn't have one - that's why you get the error.

Comment: Hi @JohnyL is there anything I can do so it won't return as boolean

Comment: Using `On Error Resume Next` hides all error messages, but the errors still occur, you just cannot see them. It's like closing your eyes which also doen't remove the error. Hiding errors don't fix them. Remove that line and see which errors you get and then fix them! • You cannot debug/fix code when using `On Error Resume Next` like you did. • I also recommend to read and apply [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: It says unable to get the pastespecial property of the range class. how to fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Like this

```
Selection.Copy

Sheets("Consolidated").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(3).PasteSpecial (xlPasteFormats)

Sheets("Consolidated").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(3).PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
```

Comment: I have a formula on some of the cell that is why I want to use paste special.

Comment: I just used like this

             With Sheets("Consolidated").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)(3)
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAllUsingSourceTheme, 
             Operation:=xlNone _
            , SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
            .PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks 
             _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
            End With